# Microsoft .Net Framework unhandled exception Category does not exist

Tags: c#

See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
 ************** Exception Text **************
 System.InvalidOperationException: Category does not exist.
 at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String 
 machine, 
 String category)at 
 System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.
 GetCounterInstances(String 
 categoryName, String machineName)
  at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()
```

I have tired all the solutions available online.

1. Uninstall and reinstall .NET Framework
2. Update Windows
3. Scan your computer for malware
4. Troubleshooting process
5. Install the .NET Framework manually
6. Run the .NET Framework repair tool
7. Perform SFC scanning
8. Clean Clean and access Safe Mode

**Note** that the application is only not working on one device, but working just fine on other devices without any issues